# Ubuntu 14.04 randomly shuts down

Tags: shutdown

I bought a new laptop BU1402 from [TUXEDO computers](http://www.tuxedocomputers.com) with Ubuntu 14.04 installed and have now experienced two unexpected shutdowns. The screen just turns black and then the notebook just turns off.

I have communicated the error to TUXEDO computers but they haven't answered.

What shall I do to find the error?

Comment: Is it due to overheating? Has there been any specific activities you do before it turns off?

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion exactly like [That Coder Guy](https://askubuntu.com/users/154752/that-coder-guy): overheating.

To be absolutely sure, install package `psensor`, run it constantly on one of your desktops, enable sensors logging on a mount volume without write-back cache (or turn write-back off for that volume temporarily)

If none of the above makes sense to you, post a comment and we'll get back to you!

---

P.S. You were gaming when it shut down, right???  ;)

P.P.S. Put a 3 cm thick book under the back of your laptop (so that your laptop's keyboard is slanted) ASAP as you'll burn out something pretty soon.  I burned out an NVIDIA Graphics card like that (luckily under warranty) before I knew what **not** to do!

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced random shutdowns / restarts in Ubuntu 14.04 / 16.04.

While watching Youtube it mostly shuts down. I also play some flash player games in browser. I tried different environment - LXDE , Unity , Gnome , etc but it was never solved. Even cleaned fan vents, without opening, by blowing air through straw. Always kept laptop in power saving mode still it had shutdown.

At last found out that Adobe Flash Player was the cause.

Uninstalled Adobe Flash no more random auto shut downs.

Try browser with adobe flash player in WINE.